# Use div height for marginTop

Tags: jquery, variables, height

I need to make a simple animation, but the problem is that they height of the contentblock is not set (depends on how much text is in it). So I figured I needed to know the height of the contentblock and put that number in the marginTop. But as you figured out, I don't know how to do that.

```
$('nav').hide().fadeIn(1200, function(){
    $('#content_home').animate({
    marginTop: '-50px'},1000);    
});
```

This is the jQuery code I use for my animation. So I need the height of #content_home and put that in the marginTop value.

I guess I need to write a function that calculates the height and puts it in a variable, and that variable  I need to put into the marginTop value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = $("#content_home").height();
```

you can also use other functions like `.innerHeight()` and `.outerHeight()` which ever one works for you.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I just fail at this stuf :). Could you quickly explain how to make the marginTop a negative value?

    marginTop: '-' result},1000);  

Does not seem to work.

Comment: this is another way -Math.abs(result)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)?

```
$('nav').hide().fadeIn(1200, function(){
    var contentHomeHeight = $('#content_home').height();
    $('#content_home').animate({
    marginTop: contentHomeHeight },1000);    
});
```

Comment: Well I think a 'px' concatenation isn't needed since as per the jQuery docs: If only a number is provided for the value, jQuery assumes a pixel unit. If a string is provided, however, a valid CSS measurement must be provided for the height (such as 100px, 50%, or auto).

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question:

> I guess I need to write a function that calculates the height and puts it in a variable, and that variable I need to put into the marginTop value.

You calculate the height of something by using the .height() function so simply:

```
$('nav').hide().fadeIn(1200, function(){
    var height = ($('#contentblock').height() * -1);

    $('#content_home').animate({
    marginTop: height},1000);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the .height() method on the jQuery $('#content_home') element?